# Three.js plane doesn't cast shadow

Tags: three.js

I'm stacking a plane and a sphere on top of a bigger plane, as seen in the following image

[image]

From WebGL inspector, it seems all three object are drawn in the shadowmap, but only the sphere is effectively appearing in the shadowmap, causing the smaller plane to never cast a shadow on the bigger one

Here's the scene construction

```
renderer.shadowMap.enabled = true

camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera(50, window.innerWidth / window.innerHeight, 1, 5000);
camera.position.z = 600;
window.controls = new THREE.OrbitControls(camera, renderer.domElement);


light = new THREE.SpotLight(0xffffff, 1, 0, Math.PI / 2);
light.position.set(1, 1000, 1);
light.castShadow = true;
light.shadow = new THREE.LightShadow(new THREE.PerspectiveCamera(50, 1, 1, 5000));

scene.add(light);

var planeGeometry = new THREE.PlaneGeometry( innerWidth * 0.5, innerHeight * 0.5, 10, 10);
var plane = new THREE.Mesh( planeGeometry, new THREE.MeshPhongMaterial({ color: 0xffcccc }));
plane.rotation.x = -Math.PI / 2;
plane.castShadow = true;
plane.receiveShadow = true;
scene.add(plane);


var sphere = new THREE.SphereGeometry(100, 16, 8);
var spheremesh = new THREE.Mesh(sphere, new THREE.MeshPhongMaterial( ));
spheremesh.position.y = 200;
spheremesh.castShadow = true;
spheremesh.receiveShadow = true;
scene.add(spheremesh);

var planeGeometry1 = new THREE.PlaneGeometry( innerWidth, innerHeight, 10, 10);
var plane1 = new THREE.Mesh( planeGeometry1, new THREE.MeshPhongMaterial( ));
plane1.position.y = -250;
plane1.rotation.x = -Math.PI / 2;
plane1.castShadow = true;
plane1.receiveShadow = true;
scene.add(plane1);
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

By default, three.js culls front faces when generating shadow maps.

That means only back faces (from the point of view of the light) cast shadows. Culling front faces of your plane leaves nothing left to cast a shadow.

So one option is to replace your `PlaneGeometry` with a thin `BoxGeometry`, which has depth.

A second option is to set

```js
material.shadowSide = THREE.DoubleSide;
```

In this case, your plane will cast a shadow, but there may be self-shadowing artifacts since you have both `plane.castShadow = true` and `plane.receiveShadow = true`.

Typically, the first option is the best option.

three.js r.151