# MeshDepthMaterial issue for shadow rendering

Tags: three.js

the shadow only shows a part but not the entire object.
in my case i have a tree, and set MeshDepthMaterial for it as the leaf of the tree are transparent. but the shadow only has trunk and no any leaves.
my model is added through OBJLoader, so i'm not sure if the problem whether caused by the model.

this is my code:

```
    loader.load("/uploads/rs/373/nqkcjvs8/bamboopalm.json", function(o) {
        var mesh = o.getObjectByName("Cylinder06");
        var mat = mtloader.load("/uploads/rs/373/nqkcjvs8/bamboopalm_1k.jpg");
        let matalpha = mtloader.load("/uploads/rs/373/nqkcjvs8/bamboopalm_1k_alpha.jpg");
        mat.anisotropy = 16;
        mesh.material = new THREE.MeshPhongMaterial({
            map:mat,
            alphaMap: matalpha,
            side: THREE.DoubleSide,
            alphaTest: .5
        });
        var depthMaterial = new THREE.MeshDepthMaterial({
            depthPacking: THREE.RGBADepthPacking,
            alphaMap: matalpha,
            alphaTest: .5
        });
        mesh.castShadow = mesh.receiveShadow = true;
        mesh.position.set(0, -50, 0);
        var scale = 10;
        mesh.scale.set(scale, scale, scale);
        mesh.customDepthMaterial = depthMaterial;
        scene.add(mesh);
    });
```

and here is an online demo: [OBJLoader Tree](http://runjs.cn/code/e6inr8d5)

as you can see, the shadow only has the tree trunk and no any leaves.

Comment: demo was fixed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

three.js culls front faces when rendering shadows. If you want your (planar) palm leaves to cast a shadow, you need to set

```
renderer.shadowMap.renderSingleSided = false;
```

See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44989568/three-js-plane-doesnt-cast-shadow/44990934#44990934) for more detail.

I strongly suggest you update to the most recent revision of three.js. I also suggest you add a helper and tighten up your shadow camera frustum for improved shadows.

```
dLight.shadowCameraHelper = new THREE.CameraHelper( dLight.shadow.camera );
scene.add( dLight.shadowCameraHelper );
```

three.js r.87

Comment: it does make sense. thanks man. besides, is there an options to set 'front' to be rendered for individual objects but not set for the renderer? will this global setting cause performance down?